# List showing the last item in the ArrayList

Tags: android, list, hashmap

I have a Simple Question.Why is this List showing the last item in the List

Any Answer Appreciated...

```
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> noteItem=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

    HashMap<String,Object> hashmapNoteItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    hashmapNoteItem.put("todo_check", false);
    hashmapNoteItem.put("todo_content", "added 0"); 

    noteItem.add(hashmapNoteItem);

    HashMap<String,Object> hashmapNoteItem1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hashmapNoteItem.put("todo_check", true);
    hashmapNoteItem.put("todo_content", "added 1"); 

    noteItem.add(hashmapNoteItem1);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At second code block you are using hashmapNoteItem instead of hashmapNoteItem1:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> noteItem=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

HashMap<String,Object> hashmapNoteItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

hashmapNoteItem.put("todo_check", false);
hashmapNoteItem.put("todo_content", "added 0"); 

noteItem.add(hashmapNoteItem);

HashMap<String,Object> hashmapNoteItem1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// changed hashmapNoteItem to hashmapNoteItem1
hashmapNoteItem1.put("todo_check", true);
hashmapNoteItem1.put("todo_content", "added 1"); 

noteItem.add(hashmapNoteItem1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: "Why is this List **NOT** showing the last item in the List"
After `noteItem.add(hashmapNoteItem1);`
add this line:
`yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`